django - how to distinguish if code in AppConfig is run by manage.py or by http server
I customized AppConfig in django to start some processes needed for the main application as described in the django documentation.

In the usual initialization process, the ready method is only called once by Django. But in some corner cases, particularly in tests which are fiddling with installed applications, ready might be called more than once. In that case, either write idempotent methods, or put a flag on your AppConfig classes to prevent rerunning code which should be executed exactly one time.

Two questions:

in my experience the ready() method is alwasys called at least twice even if it just print an hello message. How can I add the flag pointed out in the documentation?
I don't want the processes start when I run manage.py commands (ex. to migrate). How can I manage this in the code?


The flag it refers to in the documentation is an environment variable, for example:
class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "myapp.api"

    def ready(self):
        if os.environ.get("RUN_MY_THING_ONCE") == "true":
            return
        else:
            # do something
            os.environ['RUN_MY_THING_ONCE'] == "true"
            pass
            

Django actually sets a variable RUN_MAIN for this purpose when autoreloading files. I used this for registering a custom prometheus collector:
class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "myapp.api"

    def ready(self):
        if os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN"):
            from myapp.prom_exporter import CustomCollector
            from prometheus_client.core import REGISTRY

            REGISTRY.register(CustomCollector())

